# Product not visible in list product and search

Tags: magento2, product, category, search, visibility

I have a strange problem.

> http://lady-wine.com/en/brunello-di-montalcino-castelgiocondo-marchesi-de.html

This product is currently visible if I insert link directly but it's not visible with search and in products lists. Why?

Thanks
Ale

Comment: Did you reindex?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changes

Comment: Is visiblility of product set to catalog,search ?

Comment: I think this link is also not working because when I clicked this link it drives me on the home page not to the product page